# How to create Built-in object using obj-y

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am working on the RPI CM4 Board with Raspbian buster OS & I am very new to the kernel modules.
I have made a sample test case to create a basic kernel module with the reference of the following link.

[RPi-Distro/rpi-source](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/rpi-source)
With this reference, I am able to build successfully & created the following module files.

```
hello.c  hello.ko  hello.mod  hello.mod.c  hello.mod.o  hello.o  Makefile  modules.order  Module.symvers
```

But I want to create the Built-in object using obj-y.

For that, I am referring to the following [Writing a built-in object for Linux Kernel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27916116/writing-a-built-in-object-for-linux-kernel) link.

```
// hello.c

#include <linux/module.h> /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h> /* Needed for KERN_INFO */

int __init init_module(void)
{
        printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world 1.\n");
        /*
        * A non 0 return means init_module failed; module can't be loaded.
        */
        return 0;
}

void __exit cleanup_module(void)
{
        printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye world 1.\n");
}

module_init(init_module);
module_exit(cleanup_module);
```

```
// Main Makefile (inside hello directory)

obj-y   += new/
```

```
// New Makefile (inside new directory)

obj-y   += hello.o
```

By applying solution 1, I am getting the following output,

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/hello $ make -n -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd)
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.63-v7l+'
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=/home/pi/hello \
single-build= \
need-builtin=1 need-modorder=1
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=/home/pi/hello/new \
 \
need-builtin=1 \
need-modorder=1
set -e;   {  :; } | awk '!x[$0]++' - > /home/pi/hello/new/modules.order; printf '%s\n' 'cmd_/home/pi/hello/new/modules.order := {  :; } | awk '\''!x[$$0]++'\'' - > /home/pi/hello/new/modules.order' > /home/pi/hello/new/.modules.order.cmd
:
set -e;   {   cat /home/pi/hello/new/modules.order; :; } | awk '!x[$0]++' - > /home/pi/hello/modules.order; printf '%s\n' 'cmd_/home/pi/hello/modules.order := {   cat /home/pi/hello/new/modules.order; :; } | awk '\''!x[$$0]++'\'' - > /home/pi/hello/modules.order' > /home/pi/hello/.modules.order.cmd
:
:
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.modpost
make[1]: *** No rule to make target '/home/pi/hello/modules.order', needed by '/home/pi/hello/Module.symvers'.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:1729: modules] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.63-v7l+'



pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/hello $ ls
Makefile  modules.order  Module.symvers  new

pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/hello $ ls new/
hello.c  Makefile  modules.order  Module.symvers
```

Will you please help me to know, How do I create the Built-in object files using the obj-y?

Comment: What you say before "i.e. creating the static library file lib.a" doesn't match this part, as far as I can tell those things aren't related. The linked-to question doesn't mention anything about creating a library archive. I don't really understand what you're trying to do. You seem to want to link your object directly into the kernel, but seem to want to build it separately.

Comment: @ThomasJager: Firstly I would like to build the objects using the obj-y which haven't done yet & eventually whenever I am able to do that I would like to create the library using lib-y for the kernel.

Comment: For built-in object files (statically linked into the kernel), you need to modify the kernel source tree and build the kernel. The `M=` parameter is not used for building the kernel.

Comment: built-in means it must be compiled and linked into the whole kernel image. You need to rebuild the entire kernel. linux-headers does not include the source of the kernel, so can't be used.

Comment: @IanAbbott Will you please help me to know, what are the modifications, is there any document or referance for it?

Comment: @stark I have already built the kernel using the following reference [The Linux kernel](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/linux_kernel.html). I am facing the same issue. with obj-m I am able to create dynamic modules. but I want to create the static one using obj-y. will you please guide me through this?

Comment: "But I want to create the Built-in object using obj-y. For that, I am referring to the following [Writing a built-in object for Linux Kernel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27916116/writing-a-built-in-object-for-linux-kernel) link." - The accepted answer to the linked question tells that you need to modify files in the Linux kernel tree. In your output I see no evidence of such modifications. "with obj-m I am able to create dynamic modules. but I want to create the static one using obj-y." - As you have been said above, `obj-y` has a sense only while building the kernel itself.

Comment: @Tsyvarev As I mentioned above that I have applied solution 1 for the reference link. Also, I have edited the question & added the source & makefiles to it. Will you please help me to know, How can I confirm that obj-y is working or not?

Comment: Why did your kernel build not create a modules.builtin file?

Comment: @stark I am a beginner at kernel configuration & LDD.  I would like to know am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Do you see a file in the top level of the kernel source called README?  What do you think you should do with it?

Comment: I have updated the question & now I am facing the make file dependency error. How can I solve this?